# Accessing an FTP connection for downloading files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ftp

i am new to iphone.. i want guidelines for accessing ftp server through objective c  ,where ftp url, username,password should be given in program itself , i want to access a lot of image files from the ftp and display it in my imageview.

how to store those image files in locally and retrieve whenever needed....

thanks in advance..

Comment: CAPS LOCK IS CRUISE CONTROL FOR AWESOME!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ftp? Really?  With username and password?  Unless your server is *really* well configured, FTP is a security hole waiting to happen.

But... OK... to answer your question;  there is no built in FTP client API in iOS.   You'll either need to roll your own (hard, but the protocol is well documented) or use a client library (maybe easy, maybe not).

I'd start [here (yes, a google search,](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=objective-c+ftp+client&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) but not meant to be flippant) and review the various libraries to see which fits your needs better.

Note that [Omni's frameworks](http://www.omnigroup.com/company/developer) show up on that page.  They write good code.

---

However, the best solution would be to use HTTP to communicate between your app and a server.  HTTP support is built in, HTTP is ubiquitous, and it is much easier to configure a web server to be secure.

Comment: thanks for ur help. i am new to this.. so only i cant get a way to solve this problem .

Comment: It is a very hard problem, especially for someone new.  FTP has largely been avoided by the industry because it is such a big security hole.  HTTP won, is ubiquitous, and there are plenty of examples of using HTTP to solve problems like this.

Comment: Thank you, I tried my level best. Here my  colleagues are also new to iphone .Kindly share your knowledge based on the ftp connection for downloading.

Comment: That is the grand sum total;  "Don't use FTP".   The last time I used FTP was in 1998 because a client demanded it.  Their server was promptly hacked (they maintained it) and they went out of business.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with bbum, however there is FTP support in iOS, and even sample code:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243

but don't use it. use HTTPS.