# I need a good ftp client library for iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, ftp

This is my first post :) sorry for my english.

I'm looking for a library (free or not) for download/upload/rename/other stuff on my ftp server.

I know that ftp protocol is insecure and obsolete, but -at this moment- I need this protocol.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354012/uploading-and-downloading-via-ftp-with-iphone-sdk) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878825/accessing-an-ftp-connection-for-downloading-files)

However `simpleFTPSample` is too low level for my needs, and `s7ftprequest` isn't a full library but it works only for upload..

Answer (score 1):

This might help.
[chilkat iOS Library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ftp-objc.asp)

I also have been required to use ftp, and this looks like it had enough features.

For my case I just modified simpleFTP project and it has enough functionality.